# Assign separate link to each repeater item in ASP .net

Tags: asp.net, hyperlink, repeater

I was trying to develop a forum website (trying to mimic some of its features) and I am using Entity framework to get my data. I have to use repeater as my instructor asked me to do so.

I would be having something like this using repeater that gets data for "Forum Category" and "Sub-category" from 2 separate database tables:

- Forum Category 1

  - Sub-Category 1
  - Sub-Category 2
- Forum Category 2

  - Sub-Category 1
  - Sub-Category 2

Now, I would like, when clicked on those sub-category list to be directed to the page of their own using query string and that is what I am not being able to figure out at this time. When I assign a link to those sub-lists, since they are automatically generated all of them point to the page that I initially assign. I was wondering if there was someway to dynamically assign links for this scenario. I was thinking of using ENUM, but again how do I run a for loop there.

The code I have for the repeater is below:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="categoryRepeater" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="RepeaterDataBinding">
            <ItemTemplate>
              <asp:Label ID="categoryLabel" Text='<%#Eval("CatName") %>' runat ="server" 
                  style="font-weight:bold;font-size:large" />
                <br />
                <asp:Repeater ID="forumRepeater" runat="server">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <a href="DesktopForum1.aspx?ForumID=<%#Eval("ForumID") %>"><%#Eval("ForumName")%></a><br/>
                       <%-- right up there. Instead of hardcoding "DesktopForum1.aspx?ForumID=" which makes all the links
                           to point to that page, I am trying to achieve a way to assign links to specific pages for each sub-list...
                           --%>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
```

I did try searching the forum, but could not come across with a problem that resembled my situation.

Answer (score 1):

If you're able to get the sub-list page URL with the query that populates forumRepeater, this should work:

```
<a href='<%#Eval("ForumUrl")%>'><%#Eval("ForumName")%></a><br/>
```

Comment: thanks. I got it figured out, assuming somebody else might come across the same situation, I will try to explain what the issue was in my case. Well basically, my thought process was wrong, kind of. There I was trying to link each sub categories to a different page, which would display the list of the topics, replies, and views for the selected sub-category. Rather than doing that, I should have tried display the CONTENTS of the pages dynamically in the same page. So what I did was, contd...

Comment: <a href="ForumDisplay.aspx?ForumID=<%#Eval("ForumID") %>"><%#Eval("ForumName")%></a> 

in the code behind file ForumDisplay.aspx.cs (I just changed the name from "DesktopForum1" to make it more appropriate), i retrieved the query string, which would be generated dynamically, and queried my database depending on the query string. For the grid view I sent the data that I received from the query, and it was done!

Answer (score 0):

Would you like to put some acnchor for each item?

It will look like that:

```
<a name="someAnchor"></a>
```

and Link will be as follows: www.mywebsite.com/blog/posts#someAnchor

For more details: http://www.echoecho.com/htmllinks08.htm

If it is still not good, you need to handle and process querystring values with Javascript

Comment: @Andrei-Thanks for the fast response. Yes I am considering using anchor tag for each list,but I cannot think how that could be done when the sub-category list will be generated at run time. Would you be able to give some more details please? Give me a moment, let me check that link out.. Thank you, but that link is not about what I was looking for.